# Hibernate updatable=false not working on child entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am trying to prevent update child class details by using `updatable = false` on `@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", updatable = false)`

Parent entity with child details are below :

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", updatable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<CustomerAddress> customerAddressDetails;
```

And child entity is given below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_address")
public class CustomerAddress {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "customer_address_id")
  private int customerAddressId;
  @Column(name = "address")
  private String addressName;
  @Column(name = "street")
  private String street;
  @Column(name = "city")
  private String city;

  ....getter...setters...
}
```

i am trying to update customer entity as below :

```
session.update(customerObj);
```

But still values are updating in database any hint on this ?

Comment: do you mean to say that `CUSTOMER_ID` foreign key column on `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` table is being updated/changed? Please take note that `updatable=false` here only applies to the column you have specified, which is the `CUSTOMER_ID` column. Other columns of your `CUSTOMER_ADDRESS` table can still be updatable.

Comment: @Ish Here customer_id is foreign key column.

Comment: I'd like to clarify if `CUSTOMER_ID` FK column is being updated despite configuring it to be `updatable=false`?

Comment: @rajesh instead of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` specify a particular casecade type like persist,remove and etc..